# calling CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() in postgres using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have a postgresql table that I'm using to store two timestamps.  The first timestamp is inserted when a order is initiated and the second timestamp is updated when the order status is returned.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders
(    
    order_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    purchase_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    requested_amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
    order_submitted_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    order_confirmed_date TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    confirm_num INTEGER NULL
);
```

My understanding is that `TIMESTAMP` is the type while `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is the function that gets called to create the timestamp.

My confusion is here: when I insert and update a row, do I need to do anything to have the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function get called or does it happen automatically

```
'INSERT INTO orders (purchase_id, requested_amount) \
                     VALUES (%s, %s) RETURNING order_id;', 
                     (purchId, requestedAmount)

'UPDATE orders SET (confirm_num) VALUES (%s) WHERE order_id = %s',
                        (confirm_num, row_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres will automatically insert `current_timestamp` when you insert a row and do not specify values for the fields with `default` option.

When you update a row you must explicitly specify the values, if you want to change them. So your table should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders
(    
    order_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    purchase_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    requested_amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
    order_submitted_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    order_confirmed_date TIMESTAMP,
    confirm_num INTEGER NULL
);
```

and update query:

```
'UPDATE orders \
    SET (order_confirmed_date, confirm_num) = (current_timestamp, %s) \
    WHERE order_id = %s', 
    (confirm_num, row_id)
```

Comment: so my second timestamp (order_confirmed_date) remains null when the row is first inserted.  In order to update it, would I need to change my `UPDATE` call to `'UPDATE orders SET (order_confirmed_date, confirm_num) VALUES (%s, %s) WHERE order_id = %s', (order_confirm_date, confirm_num, row_id)`.  I would also have to remove default for order_confirmed_date so that it remains null when the table is first inserted?

Comment: Whoops, should UPDATE be `'UPDATE orders SET (order_confirmed_date, confirm_num) VALUES (%s, %s) WHERE order_id = %s', (current_timestamp(), confirm_num, row_id)`?

Comment: `'UPDATE orders SET (order_confirmed_date, confirm_num) VALUES (current_timestamp, %s) WHERE order_id = %s', (confirm_num, row_id)`

Comment: oh ok.  and remove `default`?

Comment: Yes, remove `default` for `order_confirmed_date`.

Comment: removed `default` and got the following `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
LINE 9:     order_confirmed_date TIMESTAMP NULL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Really? Isn't that necessary?

Comment: I tried running it but got the following error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "VALUES" at character 111
STATEMENT:  UPDATE orders SET (invested_amount, instruct_id, order_ack_date, execution_code)                              VALUES (50.0, 57396, current_timestamp, 1) WHERE order_id = 1`

Comment: In `UPDATE` there is no `VALUES` but `=`, see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The now() postgres function works with insert statements using the psycopg2 python package.

```
--Table Create Statement (SQL)
create table temp.current_timestamp_stream_test
(today_dts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
random_val varchar(200));
```

```
#Python3 to execute
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database = _xxx,
                        host = _xxx,
                        port = _xxx,
                        user = _xxx,
                        password = _xxx)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
insert into temp.current_timestamp_stream_test
(today_dts, random_val)
select now(), 'today';
""")
conn.commit()
```